# map<string, string> in class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, stl, dictionary

When I tried to compile the following codes in VS2010, error C2678 prompted.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class test
{
    private:
        map<string, string> data;
    public:
        test(){};
        ~test(){};
    public:
        const string & get(const string & key)const{return data[key];}; //error C2678
        bool set(const string & key, const string & value){data[key]=value;return true;};
};
void main()
{
    const string key="Hello world!";
    const string value="I'm coming!";
    test t;
    t.set(key,value);
    t.get(key);
}
```

But when I leave it as functions like

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
bool set(const string & key, const string & value, map<string, string> & data)
{
    data[key]=value;
    return true;
}
const string & get(const string & key, map<string, string> & data)
{
    return data[key];
}
void main()
{
    const string key="Hello world!";
    const string value="I'm coming!";
    map<string, string> data;
    set(key, value, data);
    get(key;
}
```

It does compile and runs.

Does anyone know what's the problem about?

Comment: In the future, please paste the error text, not just the number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've declared the get member function of your test class as const.  But the `std::map` `operator[]` is a non const function, so it cannot be called from a const function.  Use the `find` function instead.

The reason `operator[]` is non const is because if the key does not exist, then it inserts it into the map along with a default constructed value.

Comment: @Y.Z. : The problem is that `operator[]` inserts the key if it's not found.  So even if you don't make an assignment to it, it still might cause a change.

Comment: @Y.Z: If the passed key doesn't exist yet, the map automatically default constructs a key-value pair and adds it to the tree.

Comment: ah...that's why it's non-constant. Thank you. Question closed.

Comment: I think you mean "The reason operation[] is **not** const"

Answer (score 3):

To find an object in a `const` map, you need to use the `find` member function, you can't use `operator[]`:

```
    const string & get(const string & key)const {return data.find(key)->second;}
```

Note that this assumes the key always exists.

Comment: I don't think a map has an "at" method.